# Calculating weighted standard deviation

Tags: mysql, math, standard-deviation

I am trying to use MySQL to calculate weighted standard deviation. The following sample data will be used: the values 1 to 5, with weights 1 to 5. Here's a way to build the data:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TempTable;

CREATE TABLE TempTable (value FLOAT, weight FLOAT);
INSERT INTO TempTable (`value`, `weight`) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO TempTable (`value`, `weight`) VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO TempTable (`value`, `weight`) VALUES (3, 3);
INSERT INTO TempTable (`value`, `weight`) VALUES (4, 4);
INSERT INTO TempTable (`value`, `weight`) VALUES (5, 5);
```

Calculating the weighted mean is quite straight forward. Here how it goes:

```
SELECT SUM(`value`*`weight`) / SUM(`weight`) AS wMean
       FROM TempTable;
```

(this gives indeed 3.6666...)

However, the formula for weighted standard deviation involves the weighted mean itself. If I wish to do it in a single select statement (and I wish that), I cannot use the name `wMean` in my query, so I have to "redefine" `wMean`. This is my final result:

```
SELECT SUM(`value`*`weight`) / SUM(`weight`) AS wMean,
       SUM(POW(`value`-(SUM(`value`*`weight`) / SUM(`weight`)), 2)
           *`weight`) / SUM(`weight`) AS wStd
       FROM TempTable;
```

However, this does not work. By "does not work" I mean that the following error is printed:

```
ERROR 1111 (HY000) at line 14: Invalid use of group function
```

and the reason for that is somehow clear: the `POW` function already worked on a sum, that was iterating through all values; when comparing it to the current values and summing again, I am misusing the group function. However, this is only intuition and I am far from being a MySQL expert.

Can this be done somehow else? I really prefer not to do "subqueries" or anything fancy, as this is going to be part of a huge (~500 lines) single query, which is already complicated enough. I have no calculation-time issues, so I don't care about making redundant calculations.

Comment: There are many different ways to calculate the standard deviation and that formula uses the definition directly.  Start with the Wikipedia page and look at the "Rapid Calculation Methods".

Comment: That section is about "running" (online) calculation. I need an offline calculation - frozen set of data which is not "repeatedly updated".

Comment: I'd probably start by simplifying your huge (~500 lines) single query!

Comment: That's not an option now. However, my question stands on its own: I am interesting to find out how to perform that simple calculation using simple methods.

Comment: A subquery *is* a simple method, but you've ruled it out because of this 500-line query - so no, the question does not stand on its own.